Revert error when using getConversionRate PriceConverter file
I am writing a fundMe test file where I run tests for my fundMe solidity contract. I am having a problem concerning calling a function called "getConversionRate" from a PriceConverter file, this takes in USD and converts it to ether currency. Now when I test it in my test file, it reverts. The paths are correct and the code is from Cyfrin Updrafts GitHub repository. But for some reason, it does not work when I run it.
This is my getConversionRate and getPrice function:
`function getPrice(AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed) internal view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // ETH/USD rate in 18 digits
        return uint256(answer * 1e10);
    }

    function getConversionRate(
        uint256 ethAmount,
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed
    ) internal view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice(priceFeed);
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1e18;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }`

This is my fund function in the fundMe file:
`function fund() public payable {
        require(
            msg.value.getConversionRate(s_priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD,
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        );
        s_addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        s_funders.push(msg.sender);
    }`

This is my test file code (and yes, SEND_VALUE is more than MINIMUM_USD):
`function testFundFailsWithoutEnoughEth() public{
        fundMe.fund{value: SEND_VALUE}();
    }`


This is the error I am receiving:

forge test --match-test testFundFunctionFailsWithoutEnoughEth -vvv
[⠢] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped

Ran 1 test for test/FundMeTest.t.sol:FundMeTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] testFundFunctionFailsWithoutEnoughEth() (gas: 17135)
Traces:
  [17135] FundMeTest::testFundFunctionFailsWithoutEnoughEth()
    ├─ [5164] FundMe::fund{value: 5000000000000000000}()
    │   ├─ [0] 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
    └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert

Suite result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 808.81µs (133.50µs CPU time)      

Ran 1 test suite in 9.26ms (808.81µs CPU time): 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/FundMeTest.t.sol:FundMeTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] testFundFunctionFailsWithoutEnoughEth() (gas: 17135)

Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded



I tried not importing the PriceConverter.sol file and just inserting the functions directly into the fundMe file but it still did not work and sent back the same revert error.

